# Trying to run Jenkins behind SSL reverse proxy - 404 http://localhost/jenkins/manage vs. https:

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, jenkins

I am trying to run Jenkins behind nginx.  Jenkins runs in a Docker container, listening on Port 8080 from directory /jenkins. My nginx container has this Jenkins container linked as hostname "jenkins", so in its context, Jenkins is accessible via http://jenkins:8080/jenkins.

I followed the steps at [Running Jenkins from a folder with TLS encryption](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy) and thus my `site-config` contains this:

```
location ^~ /jenkins/ {
    sendfile off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/jenkins/;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    client_max_body_size       64m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout      90;
    proxy_send_timeout         90;
    proxy_read_timeout         90;
    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  }
```

I am now trying to access the nginx from localhost, and calling https://localhost/jenkins presents me Jenkins. However, when I go to "Manage Jenkins", I get the message that my reverse proxy setup is incorrect. I tried

```
curl -k -iL -e https://localhost/jenkins/manage \
   https://localhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test
```

which gives me a 404 with `http://localhost/jenkins/manage vs. https:`.

When I add

```
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
```

the message changes to `https://localhost/jenkins/manage vs. https:`

What am I missing?

Comment: When you use `curl` do you get a value for the `Location:` response header? This might help you add a more specific `proxy_redirect` parameter.

Comment: `curl -vvv -k -iL -e https://localhost/jenkins/manage https://localhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test 2>&1 |grep Location` gives me: 
`< Location: https://localhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fjenkins%2Fmanage/
Location: https://localhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fjenkins%2Fmanage/` - what does this tell me?

Comment: The `proxy_redirect` seems to be functioning correctly.

Comment: I think I found something interesting. The redirect seems to chop off slashes at some point. When I call:
`curl -k -iL -e https://localhost/jenkins/manage https://localhost/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/testForReverseProxySetup/a`
I get `https://localhost/jenkins/manage vs. a`, however, with
`.../testForReverseProxySetup/a/b`, I also get `... vs a`. Same with `...a%2Fb`. Any ideas?

Comment: Very strange: I now configured Jenkins and am playing around with it, and did not notice any strange behaviour yet. Plus: When I run this `curl` on my other internal Jenkins which only listens on http, I get the same 404, but I have been running it for over a year without any problems now.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem like this just now, and what solved it for me was described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20514632/1446479

My NOT working config used this line:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8015/jenkins/;
```

But my working config now looks like this:

```
location /jenkins/
{
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8015$request_uri;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
  port_in_redirect off;
  proxy_redirect http://my.host/jenkins /jenkins;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get bad gateway (even when updating my.host and proxy_pass IP address and port