# Can't access Jenkins using nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, jenkins

I had jenkins up & running using nignx but it was unsecured so I followed a couple of guides from digitalOcean [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) & [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-jenkins-with-ssl-using-an-nginx-reverse-proxy) to secure ningx with reverse proxy & ssl.

Now I can't access jenkins - I have a blog running in port 80 so did not want to redirect straight to jenkins as per the above guides so had to toy around.

Overall is not working and have changed the `default` file so many times without success.

Already tried some solutions [sol1](https://serverfault.com/questions/743110/trying-to-run-jenkins-behind-ssl-reverse-proxy-404-http-localhost-jenkins-ma), [sol2](https://serverfault.com/questions/558631/unable-to-access-jenkins-server) but no joy.

Not an expert on this matter hence reaching to you guys!

my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` looks like this:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        root /var/www/html

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name MYDOMAIN.com www.MYDOMAIN.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }       
       }
server {
               listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
               server_name jenkins.MYDOMAIN.com;
               access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
               error_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;
               location /jenkins/ {
                           include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                           proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
                           proxy_read_timeout  90s;
                           # Fix potential "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                           proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://jenkins.MYDOMAIN.com;
                       }
              # listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
               ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
               ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYDOMAIN.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
               include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   }
```

Jenkins is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep jenkins
jenkins  10876  0.0  0.4  45248  4640 ?        Ss   14:45   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
jenkins  10879  0.0  0.1 143280  1952 ?        S    14:45   0:00 (sd-pam)
jenkins  10888  0.0  0.0  18852   196 ?        S    14:45   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1
jenkins  10889  2.0 23.1 2278700 235076 ?      Sl   14:45   0:28 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1
alberto  11067  0.0  0.1  12944  1024 pts/0    S+   15:08   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn jenkins
```

### Logs:

```
cat /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log
2017/07/31 13:29:49 [error] 9874#9874: *7 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 13:29:58 [error] 9874#9874: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 186.28.102.74, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "www.MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 13:30:03 [error] 9874#9874: *15 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 13:32:34 [error] 9874#9874: *25 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 186.28.102.74, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "www.MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 13:37:04 [error] 9924#9924: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 13:37:15 [error] 9924#9924: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 14:07:20 [error] 10299#10299: *14 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: jenkins.MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 14:07:57 [error] 10299#10299: *14 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: jenkins.MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
2017/07/31 14:09:43 [error] 10299#10299: *17 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 81.159.112.19, server: jenkins.MYDOMAIN.com, request: "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/", host: "MYDOMAIN.com"
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The guides you used are pretty irrelevant since we don't know which part you followed and which not. Please post all relevant config files in their current state along with actual error messages.

Comment: followed both guides end to end - diff is I created another server block. will add logs

Comment: Why you try to connect to Jenkins with https? You could terminate https on nginx and connect to Jenkins with http.

Comment: Your configuration has `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080`, but your nginx is trying to connect to `https://127.0.0.1:8080`, which obviously fails. Are you sure this was the configuration that caused these log entries?

Comment: maybe not - I changed the config file so much - going to restart nginx and get new logs